# How to validate dynamic form in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Below is my code. According to the loop count, fName will increase. currently I am using [ng-bootstrap-form-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap-form-validation) for validation. The issue if I validate using formControlName that's not working it's duplicating if one field(fName) is correct all the fields become correct.

Below is my HTML code,

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (validSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="results-traveler" *ngFor="let item of createLoopRange(selectedDataDetails[0].Adult); let ii= index;">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 heading" *ngIf="ii == 0 else travelCount">Traveller {{ii}}</div>
  <div class="col-6 M-full-div">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <div class="inputContainer form-group">
      <input class="InputField form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type Here" formControlName="fName" id="fName_{{i}}" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="SearchBtn" type="submit">CONTINUE</a>
</form>
```

Below is the typescript code I am using,

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bookingDetailsValidate();
  }

bookingDetailsValidate() {
 this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  fName: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
  ])
});
}

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.formGroup);
}
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for `fName` use `FormArray` then add `FormControl` to `FormArray` and you can validate `FormArray` and every `FormControl` inside `FormArray`

example:

```
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  fName: new FormArray([], [
    Validators.required    
  ])
});

...

const arrayOfNameControl = this.formGroup.get('fName') as FormArray

arrayOfNameControl.insert(0, new FormControl('',[
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
]));
```

Comment: getting a error like this ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function

Comment: add `createLoopRange(selectedDataDetails[0].Adult)` items to `FormArray` and inside `html` loop over `FormArray`. add your data to your form then render form

Answer (score 0):

You need form array here. Please refer the link.

[Angular form array](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-formarray-example-in-reactive-forms/)